# Nodemailer potentially keeping Jest from exiting

Tags: node.js, jestjs, nodemailer, supertest

I am running an integration test and it works fine without requiring nodemailer. The moment I had it added, I began to get this

```
Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting:

  ●  DNSCHANNEL

      1 | require('dotenv').config()
    > 2 | const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
```

[image]

Test Script is here

```
require('dotenv').config()

const supertest = require('supertest')
const app = require('../app_test')

// const server = supertest.agent("http://localhost:" + process.env.ACCESS_TEST_PORT)

beforeAll(() => {
    process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test'
})

describe('Testing', () => {
    it('Testing if my sample test works!', () => {
        expect(true).toBe(true)
    })
})

describe('Testing the Index Page', () => {
    it('It should return statusCode 200', (done) => {
        supertest(app)
            .get('/v1/')
            .expect(200)
            .end((err, res) => {
                if (err) return done(err);
                expect(res.body).toEqual(
                    expect.objectContaining({
                        statusCode: 200,
                        message: 'This serves as a repository of API calls for INPAY application'
                        // token: expect.any(String),
                        // user: expect.any(Object),
                    }),
                );
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This has been figured out. I realized that I added a flag that detects Open handles (--detectOpenHandles), hence the reason for the the messages